# Whenever I compile my code in my device it works just fine with any input. But when I submit the code with unknown inputs it gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int n=0;
    int i=0, j=0, k=0, l=0, index=0; 
    int max = 0; 
    int letters = 0; 
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int indexes[10][n]; 
    int erase=0; 
    int result=0;
    char name[n][10]; 
    for(j=0 ; j<10 ; j++){
        for(k=0 ; k<n ; k++){
            indexes[j][k] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        scanf("%s", name[i]);  
    }
    for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        if(strcmp(name[i],"Stop") == 0){
            continue;
        }
        max = 0;
        for(j=0 ; j<strlen(name[i]) ; j++){
            letters = 1;
            index = 0;
            for(k=i+1 ; k<n ; k++){
                if(strcmp(name[k],"Stop") == 0){
                    continue;
                }
                for(l=0 ; l<strlen(name[k]) ; l++){
                    if(name[i][j] == name[k][l]){
                        letters++;
                        indexes[j][index] = k;
                        index++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(letters > max){
                max = letters;
                erase = j;
            }
        }
        for(j=0 ; j<n ; j++){
            if(strcmp(name[indexes[erase][j]], "Stop") == 0 || max == 1){ 
                break;
            }
            strcpy(name[indexes[erase][j]],"Stop");
        }
        result++;
    }
    printf("%d",result);
    return 0;    
}
```

It works just fine. But when I submit it for the school project with unknown inputs it gives segmentation error. What causes this? The code should take a list of strings and sort them into lists of strings that have same letters. It should print out the minimum number of lists. Which is what the code does. The first number can be up to 100000 and the length of strings are always shorter or equal to 10

For example:
inputs:
3
aa
bb
cc
output:
3

inputs:
3
ab
bc
cd
output:
2 ([[ab,bc],[bc,cd]])

Comment: You seem to have forgotten that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. This *null-terminator* needs space as well, which means that a string of 10 character needs space for **11** to fit the terminator.

Comment: Oh yes thank you. Now it works. But it seems it doesn't print out the correct solution now. Oh well :D